# Missing Data Plotly Express px.data

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

In the example from here

https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/#plotly-express-works-with--long-wide-and-mixedform-data

there is only one line for data import: `wide_df = px.data.medals_wide()`

I tried on my Python via Anaconda and get this `Traceback: AttributeError: module ‘plotly.express.data’ has no attribute ‘medals_wide’`

I just tried this code:

```
for name in dir(px.data):
    if '__' not in name:
        print(name)
```

and get

```
absolute_import
carshare
election
election_geojson
gapminder
iris
tips
wind
```

based on the result I miss a few data including the medals one, then I tried to re-install Plotly and Plotly Express under Anaconda Prompt but the problem persists

```
Successfully installed plotly-express-0.4.1
```

when I tried `pip install plotly` to update in case
I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: plotly in c:\users\ appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: retrying>=1.3.3 in c:\users\ appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from plotly) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from plotly) (1.14.0)
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your *plotly* version?

Comment: not sure, just updated my post to reply your question. this is what I got when I tried pip install plotly: Requirement already satisfied: plotly in c:\users\ appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: retrying>=1.3.3 in c:\users\ appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from plotly) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from plotly) (1.14.0)

Comment: run `import plotly`, and then `plotly.__version__`

Comment: `__version__` Double underscores at the end too

Comment: 4.7.1, I am trying "pip install plotly==4.14.3" now as mine doesn't seem to be the latest version

Comment: problem solved, do you prefer to paste your above answer as official answer to my question so that I can confirm it as answer to my question?

Comment: Sure! Will do it promptly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be available if you update to Plotly version `4.14`.

Check your current version with:

```
import plotly
plotly.__version__
```

And if necessary run:

```
pip install plotly==4.14.3
```